# Would like some help formulating an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, sampling, monte-carlo

I have a function $f$ that takes $n \geq 1$ positive real-valued arguments $\mathbf{a} \in R^n_+$. This function is defined for all amounts of inputs (e.g. $f(1)$ and $f(3, \pi, 17)$ are both valid) and returns to me a score in the range of $[-\inf, 1]$. I want to find the smallest $n$ and the values of those $n$ arguments that maximizes $f$. How can I formulate (and hopefully solve) this optimization problem?

I'm thinking it should be something like:

$$
\begin{align}
(\hat n, \hat{\mathbf a}) = \underset{n, \mathbf{a}}{\arg\max} \; & (-n, f(\mathbf{a})) \\
\text{s.t.} &\; n = |\mathbf{a}| \\
&\; a_i > 0 \; \forall i 
\end{align}
$$

and maybe I can solve it using Markov Chain Monte Carlo? Could someone please help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is $f(a)$ differentiable?

Comment: Numerically, yes, but not symbolically, as far as I know. I have "black box" access to $f$ but it appears smooth.

Comment: Ok, then replace the analytic gradient in my post with a call to a nonlinear optimizer that solves the instance for $n$. If you start with $n=1$ and go down, then the first local minima you hit will be the one with the largest (least negative) n.

Answer (score 0):

Due to you have a restriction, maybe an approach using Lagrange's polynomials could help, but I don't have any idea of how to depict the process.